# Default CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences

How to decide whether to use this:

```
<com.package.CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="time12"
        android:title="@string/ar_title"
        android:summaryOn="@string/ar_sum_on"
        android:summaryOff="@string/ar_sum_off"/>
```

or to use:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="time12"
        android:title="@string/ar_title"
        android:summaryOn="@string/ar_sum_on"
        android:summaryOff="@string/ar_sum_off"/>
```

at run time? I mean at the preference activity onCreate method?

Comment: What is `com.package.CheckBoxPreference`? In code have `CheckBoxPreference` and in your imports you have the full name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same class in both places.

If you are using `com.package.CheckBoxPreference` in your XML, then you should also use `com.package.CheckBoxPreference` in your PreferenceActivity.

If you use the stock `CheckBoxPreference` in your XML, you should make sure you are using `android.preference.CheckBoxPreference` in your PreferenceActivity.

Comment: I'm using this because I'm creating a custom layout for my CheckBoxPreference dynamically by extending the CheckBoxPreference class.  in the com.package.CheckboxPreference I'm returning a custom layout in the onCreate mmethod. all of that depends on a certain situation. if that situation is changed, I want to use the default CheckBoxPreference.